# Cambiar formato de fecha a español con Jquery y Moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, momentjs

Tengo este pequeño fragmento de código que me genera la hora y fecha con ayuda de la libreria moment.js en su version 2.22 y se va actualizado constantemente dicha fecha y hora. El problema es que especificamente la fecha me la arroja en ingles, pero quiero tener esa fecha en español, intente descargando moment-with-locales.js e integrandolo en mis paginas pero igual la fecha sigue en ingles

este es el codigo Jquery que tengo:

```js
var datetime = null,
        date = null;

    var update = function () {
       date = moment(new Date())
       datetime.html(date.format('HH:mm'));
       datetime2.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'));
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        datetime = $('.time h1');
        datetime2 = $('.time p');
        update();
        setInterval(update, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="time">
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Hay alguna forma de que la fecha se pueda convertir a español? o alguna otra forma de lograr que se me muestre la hora y fecha y realice el mismo comportamiento (actualizar los valores con el setInterval para que parezca una especie de reloj) sin necesidad de usar por ejemplo moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente puedes incluir la librería **[`moment-with-locale.js`](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)**

Y poner esto al principio:

```
   moment.locale('es');
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
var datetime = null,
  date = null;

var update = function() {
  moment.locale('es');
  date = moment(new Date());
  datetime.html(date.format('HH:mm:ss'));
  datetime2.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY'));
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  datetime = $('.time h1');
  datetime2 = $('.time p');
  update();
  setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="time">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="nowDateTime">
  <h1 id="hora"></h1>
  <p id="fecha"></p>
</div>
```

---

Lo puedes hacer también con Javascript puro, prescindiendo de jQuery:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    moment.locale('es');
    var updates = function() {
    var elFecha = document.querySelector("#fecha");
    var elHora = document.querySelector("#hora");
    var nowDate = moment(new Date());
    elHora.textContent = nowDate.format('HH:mm:ss');
    elFecha.textContent = nowDate.format('dddd DD [de] MMMM [de] YYYY');
  }
  setInterval(updates, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div class="nowDateTime">
  <h1 id="hora"></h1>
  <p id="fecha"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Me han funcionado a la perfección ambas soluciones. Muchas Gracias